# Solution of the congruence $103a\equiv 1\mod 101$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I find a solution to the congruence
$103a\equiv 1\mod 101$?

Comment: $2a\equiv 1 \pmod{101}$ and $\gcd(2,101)=1$ so $a \equiv \frac{1}{2}\equiv \frac{102}{2} \equiv 51 \pmod{101}$

Comment: See the linked dupes for many ways to solve linear congruences, e.g. the above comment uses the fifth method in my answer in the second dupe, that **division by 2** is trivial for an odd modulus, since we can force the dividend to be even by adding (or subtracting) the modulus (and that's a special case of the next method, **inverse reciprocity**, which in turn is a special case of the **extended Euclidean algorithm** - the master method)